# How to upload image without form submit in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 5, I want to save image on server from input type file uploader.

Form submit,

```js
secondForm: function (e) {  
ar idfileTitle = document.getElementById("idfileTitle"); /*This fileuploader Id*/    
  
var idfileLogo = document.getElementById("idfileLogo"); /*This fileuploader Id*/    
  
 var json = {};  
  
           var hidvalue = $('#hdPrimUserFirstReg').val();  /*This is the hiddenfield Id*/
           var hidJson = JSON.parse(hidvalue);  
  
           $.each($('#frmSubmitPremUserRegFirst').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {  
               json[field.name] = field.value || '';  
           });  
  
           hidJson.Form2 = json;  
           $formData = new FormData();  
           if (idfileTitle.files.length > 0) {  
               for (var i = 0; i < idfileTitle.files.length; i++) {  
                   $formData.append('file-' + i, idfileTitle.files[i]);  
               }  
           }  
  
           if (idfileLogo.files.length > 0) {  
               for (var i = 0; i < idfileLogo.files.length; i++) {  
                   $formData.append('file-' + i, idfileLogo.files[i]);  
               }  
           }  
  
/*Here 'hidJson' containing all form data*/      
  
           $.ajax({  
               url: '../UserRegister/PremiumUserRegistration/' + hidJson,  
               type: 'POST',  
               data: $formData,  
               dataType: 'json',  
               contentType: false,  
               processData: false,  
               success: function ($data) {  
                   $('#frmregitems').html($data);  
               }  
           });
```

Controller,

Here `pageVM`is null passing while assigning `hidJson`to `PremiumUserRegistration` action method as param.

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PremiumUserRegistration(RegistrationModel pageVM)
    {
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        foreach (string fil in files)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here, `Request.Files` also containing only one image details, How can get multiple images from `Request.Files` ?

Please help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24939229/74015

Comment: I have update my question here, Now I can save only one image to server through ajax submit. But how can I save multiple images?